# Bittorrent client makes multiple connections upon its start to amazonaws

Tags: networking, connection, bittorrent, tcp

I have this weird situation that every time I open my bittorrent client application, upon its start, it starts to make a lot of multiple connections(more than thousands) to amazonaws servers and as you can see, all of the connections statuses are SYN_SENT

the number of connections are so high that during the first 20 or 30 seconds of the application start, my computer will become very slow and the application continues to make new connections for few minutes and then stops after few minutes and then the connections start to close gradually and in the end after 5 or 6 minutes from the application start, everything will go back to normal.

here is a sample the the connections:

BitTorrent.exe   TCP    my-pc   49788   ec2-23-23-85-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com  http    SYN_SENT

I've read the the application is looking for the update and also some seedboxes are using amazonaws servers.

As these connections start to created at the same time I run the application and even before the application load my torrents list so downloading torrents from the amazon servers is not my case. and about the update, I'm not sure, but making this much connections is way more that what is neede to check for the update.

I've searched for this problem, but did not find any results.

So does anyone have same problem as I have or know the solution for my case?

Comment: Which client are you using and you didn't provide us anything to see

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm using BitTorrent 7.9.2 32-bit

Comment: I had included one sample of my connections in the post

Comment: You actually didn't mention what client you were using at least not the version.

Comment: @Ramhound OK, I did not mention the version cause I did not thought it's required. but I mentioned the client name. anyway, thanks for your point and I added the version in the comments. so do you have any solutions for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling it's the DHT startup. When you first start the client, it's trying to join the DHT swarm (iirc the initial bootstrap node is node0.bittorrent.org) which would then pass you off to a bunch of other nodes, probably in a datacenter like AWS, before you get regular everyday nodes (other clients)

Comment: The sample says TCP. The DHT uses UDP.

Comment: Thanks for you comment and time, this issue was really bothering me and I could not solve it myself. but fortunately the issue had been solved by itself after I assume the new BitTorrent update to version 7.9.3, but thanks again for your concern.

Comment: Fair enough EhsanT

Doh, missed that @Encombe